# Proper syntax highlighting in Sublime 3 for a file written in several languages

Tags: syntax-highlighting, sublimetext3

I am editing e.g. shell scripts with [here-documents](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) in other languages (awk, python, R, JavaScript, you name it). Sublime 3 guesses the overall syntax but doesn't do that for the included here-document.

How can I prod Sublime in the requisite direction, e.g. by placing any special comments in the code before and after here-docs?

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "This is a test"

awk '/test/' - <<EOF
 **This** used to be a test in Markdown.
 But this line isn't included in the _output_.
EOF
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been looking for a way to do that since posting the question, and it looks like one has to roll up a new theme to support mixed languages. There is one plugin though that may fit the requirements after some re-development:

https://github.com/ProjectCleverWeb/MultiLang

It is more than two years old (early 2013), and has not seen any development since then. It remains to be seen if anybody else picks up the project.

The official forum has this: https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=14215&p=53963&#p53963 and this: https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=10843&p=42743

Either way, changes to settings/theme are required.